# Yii2: How to get around the "the data being deleted is outdated" when using optimistic locking?

Tags: yii, yii2, optimistic-locking

I am writing todo app in Yii2 using optimistic Locking.
I need to write delete action now.
How to get around the "the data being deleted is outdated" when using optimistic locking?
As we know when optimistic lock is enabled this rule works:
"if optimistic locking is enabled and the data being deleted is outdated."

It is occuring when I try to call delete method. Link:
[How to write delete action using Optimistic Locking in Yii2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75640981/how-to-write-delete-action-using-optimistic-locking-in-yii2)
Thank You!

Comment: Why are you creating new question about same issue? You should edit your previous question instead.

Comment: It is another question. You didn't read even))) Thank You for feedback!